# Extra mouse buttons not working anymore

Tags: mouse

The mouse thumb forward/backward buttons -mapped as Button4 / Button5 Mouse- aren't working anymore. Any ideas where to investigate?

[image: pic]

Otherwise the buttons are working e.g. `$ xev`:

```sh
ButtonPress event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0x114, subw 0x0, time 10644434, (1868,1507), root:(1868,1507),
    state 0x10, button 3, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0x114, subw 0x0, time 10644649, (1868,1507), root:(1868,1507),
    state 0x410, button 3, same_screen YES
```

**Even in Firefox the buttons work flawless** without any problems (forward/backward)

Tested on blender 2.93 / 3.1 (Linux)

Comment: If the driver is sending the event but Blender is not seeing it, odds are that something else is intercepting the even and either not passing it on or changing its type before passing it on.  NVIDIA drivers are noted for the former, but usually when they intercept an event they do something visible.  Have you added any Blender-unrelated software that might be intercepting mouse events?

Comment: @MartyFouts I'm indeed using nvidia drivers, even an old one (version 470.74) due to incompatibility with never versions. For other software I can't say for sure, hence it might be the cause. Any ideas on how to further investigate?

Comment: Check out the NVidia forums for questions about "disable shared hotkeys" or similar and see if they've got a way to determine it for your setup.  I use Nvidia's "Control Panel" App on windows and it has tools but I don't know about Linux or MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by removing `~/.xbindkeysrc` containing

```
# Mouse thumb forward / backward button
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\[XF86Back]""
m:0x0 + b:8 
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\[XF86Forward]""
m:0x0 + b:9
```

Apparently these once needed Webbrowser key remappings seem not only obsolete but causing the issue